# Order of Operations for Jinja2 Filters?

Tags: python, jinja2, rounding

I'm not sure of the limits of Jinja, so this might not be possible... I'm trying to calculate a percentage of two variables I've passed into Jinja, but I can't get it to round properly. What I'd like to have is something like:

```
{{ spygames / games|length * 100 | round(0) | int }}
```

Which gets the correct number (66.666666, since spygames is 2 and there are 3 games), but it renders as "66.6666666667" (I add the % sign in the html) and I want it to just be "67".

I've also tried this by getting the length of games in python and passing it in as a separate integer value, but it still has the same result.

How can I round this down to a whole number?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Jinja documentation doesn't specify any precedence rules, but I strongly suspect that the filter is only applied to the `100` literal just before it.

Group your expressions to make sure that a filter is applied to the outcome of the expression:

```
{{ (spygames / games|length * 100) | round(0) | int }}
```

Personally, I'd use the [`str.format()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format); it has a `%` percentage formatting option that includes multiplication by 100:

```
{{ '{:.0%}'.format(spygames / games|length) }}
```

This *does* add a percent sign to the output.

Comment: Okay, great! Thanks so much for the help — I'll try out the second option since it seems easier. I didn't know that was a function so very helpful to learn it.

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon — I tried that second format and I got an error: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute '0%'

Comment: @dangr: that's because there was a colon missing.. Mea Culpa!

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm. Much obliged!